# Hadoop parameter mapreduce.map.memory.mb and mapreduce.map.java.opts

Tags: hadoop, memory, memory-management, jvm, hadoop-yarn

Wondering what are the relationship between the two parameters (mapreduce.map.memory.mb and mapreduce.map.java.opts), and sometimes I see people setup mapreduce.map.memory.mb to be 2048 and mapreduce.map.java.opts to be `-Xmx4G -Xms4G -server`, wondering what are the upper limit bound in this case? Thanks.

regards,
Lin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

mapreduce.map.memory.mb is resource limit for maps.

mapreduce.map.java.opts is heap-size for child jvms of maps.

The Hadoop setting is more of a resource enforcement/controlling one and the Java is more of a resource configuration one.

The Java heap settings should be smaller than the Hadoop container memory limit because we need reserve memory for Java code. Usually, it is recommended to reserve 20% memory for code.

Comment: Thanks shekhar, vote up. :) For your comments, “mapreduce.map.memory.mb is resource limit for maps”, as you also mentioned Hadoop container, and wondering if you mean mapreduce.map.memory.mb is the limit for Hadoop map container?

Comment: @LinMa thats right, mapreduce.map.memory.mb is limit for yarn mapper container. If this limit is exceeded, Hadoop will kill the mapper.

Comment: Thanks shekhar, vote up. Besides JVM itself, any other additional usage on memory of Hadoop map container (so it is why you said reserve 20% memory for code)?

Comment: @LinMa It is beside jvm heap not jvm. Beside heap jvm need memory for  interned strings, other native overheads...

Comment: Thanks shekhar for the patience to clarify and vote up. Want to confirm my understanding is correct, the JVM memory size is the same as that of container and JVM heap (part of JVM) is best practice to set to be 80% of JVM? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa container size is maximum limit of JVM size permitted, in map reduce it is recommended to keep jvm heap size 80% of container size but that can vary depending on your usecase.

Comment: Thanks shekhar, mark your reply as answer. Appreciate for all the support.